# <exceptionMessage>[Ljava.lang.String; incompatible with java.lang.String</exceptionMessage>

Tags: java, string, web-services

I am taking the request parameters from the front-end web app and displaying the result accordingly.

```
Map<String,Object> requestparms

testObj.setUserId(requestparms.get("userId") == null ? null :requestparms.get("userId").toString());
```

When I test using the restClient I get the following error :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error incidentId="22854566" correlationId="922f4150-4636-4b94-8ac6-71f8ed1935c1">
    <exceptionMessage>[Ljava.lang.String; incompatible with java.lang.String</exceptionMessage>
</error>
```

I tried

```
String userId = String.valueOf(requestparms.get("userId"));
System.out.println("The value of variable is " +userId);
```

Still the same error.

Can you someone please with help information related to it ?

Thank you in advance,
Lucky

Comment: Where are you populating the map?

Comment: Seems like a `String[]` instead of a `String`.

Comment: possibly caused by attempting to set a String using an Object. Calling toString() on an object is probably not giving you what you want.

Comment: @RohitJain The map is populated Map<String,Object> testRequestValues=httprequest.getParameterMap(); TestRequest testRequest=RequestParser.createtestObjectFromRequest(testRequestValues);

Answer (score 0):

Try typecasting as per below

```
Map<String,Object> requestparms

testObj.setUserId(requestparms.get("userId") == null ? null:(String)requestparms.get("userId").toString());
```

Otherwise, may be MAP is not understood by REST client??
SOAP doesn't know how to parse MAP so i believe REST is same....

If this is the issue then try using JSON. It definitely works...